# App crashes when trying to add multiple textviews dynamically through loop. It works fine when adding a single text view

Tags: android, android-studio

the Numbers Activity crashes when I try to add multiple text view dynamically through the below code. but it works fine when I do not use the loop but just add the text view.

**Numbers Activity.java**

```
    public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);

        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        words.add("one");
        words.add("two");
        words.add("three");
        words.add("four");
        words.add("five");
        words.add("six");
        words.add("seven");
        words.add("eight");
        words.add("nine");
        words.add("ten");

        LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootView);
        rootView.removeAllViews();
        TextView  wordView = new TextView((this));
        int index;
        for(index=0; index<words.size(); index++ ){
            wordView.setText(words.get(index));
            rootView.addView(wordView);

        }
    }
}
```

activity_numbers.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".NumbersActivity"
</LinearLayout>
```

Error I am getting is after the app crashes is

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.yusuf.miwok, PID: 12226
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yusuf.miwok/com.example.yusuf.miwok.NumbersActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on
>   the child's parent first.
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4976)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4807)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4747)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4720)
>                         at com.example.yusuf.miwok.NumbersActivity.onCreate(NumbersActivity.java:40)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7372)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3147)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921) 
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 12226 SIG: 9 Application terminated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct code is as follow

```
 public class NumbersActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);

        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        words.add("one");
        words.add("two");
        words.add("three");
        words.add("four");
        words.add("five");
        words.add("six");
        words.add("seven");
        words.add("eight");
        words.add("nine");
        words.add("ten");

        LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootView);
        rootView.removeAllViews();

        int index;
        for(index=0; index<words.size(); index++ ){
            TextView  wordView = new TextView((this));
            wordView.setText(words.get(index));
            rootView.addView(wordView);

        }
    }
}
```

note that I just moved this line to inside the for loop

```
TextView  wordView = new TextView((this));
```